# Should I install all plugins to my new installation

Tags: qgis, plugins

I am new to QGIS and I am preparing for first time use. Should I install all plugins that are not installed?

Comment: do you need them? some are now core to QGIS installs (referring to 3.8 and the up and coming 3.10).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no need. I've been using QGIS for years and I'd guess that I've used maybe 3-5%  of the plugins that are available. Loads of them are for niche processes, locations, or are in a different language. Just install them as you need them. I occasionally have a browse through them to see if there are any that might be useful as my uses change.

Comment: Thanks TeddyTedTed. Are there any basic ones I should install?

Comment: `"Plugins Choices"` is a subjective and disputable topic. You may check this source [QGIS Python Plugins Repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/?sort=-downloads) and filter it by the total sum of downloads, or by votes. IMHO those might be interesting: QuickMapServices, MMQGIS, QuickOSM etc.

Comment: These plugins : autoSaver, changeDataSource, Memory Layer Saver and QuickMapServices  may be useful regardless of what kind of work you intend to do

Answer (score 1):

No need, it will make QGIS slower to load/start also if you have too many plugins installed.